# Follow Path - change Point of following

Tags: animation, path

I would like to change point on the path that is followed by my object. I do not want to move my object - only change point on the curve that is followed.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: so if you edit the curve, you can't get what you want?

Comment: No. In Edit Mode I can move vertices of path, but I do not want to change path. I want only change point that is followed by object (change blue hatched line connecting object and path - change place on the path that object is connected)

Comment: the easiest way is to go in the Follow Path constraint and to play with the Offset

Comment: Thank you. So do it with: change offset to change position of the blue line connecting object and path and then I move object to old position. Thank you.